# Quasar: How do I "fullscreen" the width of my dialog from q-select?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I'm currently using the `q-select__dialog` class to customize my dialog and I can't figure out how to make my dialog width kind of like full screen (i don't know the right term). I tried setting the width to 100% but the width is still not fullscreen. Any idea how I should about this?

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/codeblues_/pen/YzxNZNr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set `max-width` and it will work.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/eYEGxBb

Comment: For me it was `full-width`